# How to do masking on body?

Tags: box2d

I am new to box2d and I am working on small game. I have different actor in my game like

1. Enemies
2. Player
3. Background
4. Bullet

By default in box2d all body collide with each other. I want to remove collision on some body as like this

Enemies will collide with player.
 Player will collide with Enemies and ground.
 Background will not collide with anything 
 Bullet will collide with ground only.

I have written code as mention below

//Actor Util to create all actor

public class ActorUtils {

```
public static World createWorld() {
    return new World(Constants.WORLD_GRAVITY, true);
}

public static Body createGround(World world, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(x, y));
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(width, height);
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(shape, Constants.GROUND_DENSITY);

    Filter filterData = fixture.getFilterData();
    filterData.categoryBits = ActorMasking.CATEGORY_GROUND;
    filterData.maskBits = ActorMasking.MASK_GROUND;
    body.setUserData(new GroundUserData(Constants.GROUND_WIDTH, Constants.GROUND_HEIGHT));
    fixture.setFilterData(filterData);
    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}

public static Body createRunner(World world) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(0, Constants.RUNNER_Y));
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(Constants.RUNNER_WIDTH / 2, Constants.RUNNER_HEIGHT / 2);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(shape, Constants.RUNNER_DENSITY);
    body.resetMassData();
    body.setUserData(new RunnerUserData(Constants.RUNNER_WIDTH, Constants.RUNNER_HEIGHT));


    Filter filterData = fixture.getFilterData();
    filterData.categoryBits = ActorMasking.CATEGORY_PLAYER;
    filterData.maskBits = ActorMasking.MASK_PLAYER;
    fixture.setFilterData(filterData);

    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}

public static Body createEnemy(World world) {
    EnemyType enemyType = RandomUtils.getRandomEnemyType();
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;

    float minX = 25.0f;
    float maxX = 40f;

    float minY = 1.5f;
    float maxY = 14.0f;
    Random rand = new Random();

    float finalX = rand.nextFloat() * (maxX - minX) + minX;

    float finalY = rand.nextFloat() * (maxY - minY) + minY;

    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(/*enemyType.getX()*/finalX, /*enemyType.getY())*/finalY));
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(enemyType.getWidth() / 2, enemyType.getHeight() / 2);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(shape, enemyType.getDensity());
    body.resetMassData();
    EnemyUserData userData = new EnemyUserData(enemyType.getWidth(), enemyType.getHeight(), enemyType.getRegions());
    body.setUserData(userData);


    Filter filterData = fixture.getFilterData();
    filterData.categoryBits = ActorMasking.CATEGORY_ENEMY;
    filterData.maskBits = ActorMasking.MASK_ENEMY;
    fixture.setFilterData(filterData);

    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}


public static Body createBullet(World world, Player player) {
    BulletType bulletType1 = BulletType.BULLET_TYPE_1;
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    float finalX = player.body.getPosition().x;
    float finalY = player.body.getPosition().y;
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(finalX, finalY/*+0.5f*/));

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(bulletType1.getWidth() / 2, bulletType1.getHeight() / 2);
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(shape, 0.0f);


    body.resetMassData();
    BulletUserData userData = new BulletUserData(bulletType1.getWidth(), bulletType1.getHeight());
    body.setUserData(userData);


    Filter filterData = fixture.getFilterData();
    filterData.categoryBits = ActorMasking.CATEGORY_BULLET;
    filterData.maskBits = ActorMasking.MASK_BULLET;
    fixture.setFilterData(filterData);

    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}
```

}

//Masking class for all category and masking bits

public class ActorMasking {

```
public static final short CATEGORY_ENEMY = 0x0001;
public static final short CATEGORY_PLAYER = 0x0002;
public static final short CATEGORY_GROUND = 0x0004;
public static final short CATEGORY_BULLET = 0x008;


public static final short MASK_PLAYER = CATEGORY_ENEMY | CATEGORY_GROUND;
public static final short MASK_ENEMY = CATEGORY_PLAYER| CATEGORY_GROUND;
public static final short MASK_GROUND = CATEGORY_PLAYER | CATEGORY_BULLET;
public static final short MASK_BULLET = CATEGORY_GROUND;
```

}

it is not working as my player will collide with Enemies,Enemies collide with player. But My Bullet will not collide with ground it collide with player.

Please help.

Comment: I am also having same issue

Comment: Try to use the Andengin it is good framework. and i have solve issue.

Comment: CATEGORY_WALL=1;CATEGORY_BOX=2;CATEGORY_CIRCLE=4;MASK_WALL=CATEGORYBIT_WALL+CATEGORYBIT_BOX+CATEGORYBIT_CIRCLE;
MASKBITS_BOX=CATEGORYBIT_WALL+CATEGORYBIT_BOX;MASKBITS_CIRCLE=CATEGORYBIT_WALL+CATEGORYBIT_CIRCLE;
FixtureDef WALL_FIX_DEF=PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0,0.5f,0.5f, false,CATEGORYBIT_WALL,MASKBITS_WALL,(short)0);
FixtureDef BOX_FIX_DEF=PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1,0.5f,0.5f, false,CATEGORYBIT_BOX,MASKBITS_BOX,(short)0);
FixtureDef CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF=PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 0.5f, 0.5f, false,CATEGORYBIT_CIRCLE,MASK S_CIRCLE,(short)0);

Comment: does your issue is resolve? @user1182217